# What is downloaded as app from AppStore?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, app-store, size, ipa

I am developing with Xamarin IOS. Recently I have faced the problem of too large APP size of my iOS application. I have enabled all things from iOS build menu that can help reduce app size such as Linker, LLVM optimizer and so on.

Unfortunatelly it has reduced app size not enough. In App Store it has something around 86Mb, what is over the top.

Than I have noticed such thing in build menu as Supported Architectures.[image: Supported Architectures]

In configuration of two architectures (ARMv7 + ARM64) it produces two app files in app archive.
[image: Two output files]whereas if target only ARM64 it would be only one: [image: One output].

So, my questions:

**What does AppStore sends to user device when the one downloads the Application?** Does it sends only necessary files ore all at once? How can I check estimated AppStore sizes of output apps for each CPU Architecture? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ARMv7 and ARM64 are just used to support different architectures ,and all files generated by your app will be packaged into a ipa file. When downloading app form app store, it is actually downloading the ipa file.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT, So it means the more the architectures I support - the more the binaries are downloaded to the device that needs actually one file to launch app? Then why my .ipa file takes size of 63MB and on AppStore my app is >90Mb?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88420/app-size-is-almost-2x-bigger-than-original-ipa-in-app-store